# What are the webs under Spidey's arms for?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man

In the older Spider-man comics (although it pops again every now and then) he is almost always drawn with webbing in his arm pits as part of his costume.

[image: Spidey's weird arm pits]

Have these things been given any function in Spidey canon?

Comment: Perhaps he's part [flying squirrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_squirrel)?

Comment: Obviously they're heat sinks, to help keep his pits cool and odor free.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### The Spider-Man costume was created by seminal Spider-Man artist Steve Ditko. The webbing under Spider-Man's arms had no particular purpose, other than ornamentation. Unlike Spider Woman's underarm webbing which actually helped her fly, Spidey's webbing was just for visual effect.

[image: From Amazing Fantasy #15, origin of Spiderman story, 1962]

The webs were something Ditko liked and continued to do on and off for years. They were drawn so large, for a time they looked like wings and even other artists questioned if they could have another purpose.

When John Romita started drawing Spider-Man after Ditko left he drew the webbing smaller and smaller and eventually left them off, altogether. If you have never had the pleasure of reading Amazing Fantasy #15, first tale of Spider-Man, no fears True Believer, you can read it [**here**](http://www.superherostuff.com/blog/comic-books/retro-comics-spider-man-amazing-fantasy-15/).

[image: Amazing Spider-Man #1, 1964]

When the Amazing Spider-Man #1 came out they included a list of things Spider-Man was able to create with his webbing. This included creating a parachute!

[image: Uses of webbing]

Comment: Awesome answer.  I laughed out loud at the skis.  I really really want to see those used in a good story.

Comment: Back when Spider-Man wasn't a life or death struggle EVERY issue, almost all of these were used at one time or another. It is a sad thing that so much of what made comics fun (at least for me as a kid) is gone. We have all angst comics, all angst, all the time...

Comment: @Thaddeus Yeah I miss all those crazy web creations as well. Angsty Spiderman doesn't sit too well with me.

Comment: Seems like they just ran out of ideas after _A Barrier_. Skis, a raft and a ball...

Comment: @KyleJones - [This one's](http://www.spiderfan.org/shows/images/spiderman_tv_1960s/s01e18/screen04.jpg) for you...

Comment: @Richard LOL.  I wonder where he got the fuel for the motor.  Wait... he built a motor out of webbing?

Comment: Now I want to read an alternate universe comic in which MacGyver becomes Spider-man.

Comment: I find it funny that in the same page he talks about wearing the suit under his clothes, he has these huge web wings.

Answer (score 0):

I previously answered a question similar to this as to whether Spidey has ever used the under arm webbing for *gliding.* Most of the same answers apply here: in most cases in the comic, the under arm webs are there as a purely *stylistic* choice for more dramatic affect; they are simply too small to be used for "Gliding" purposes, as they are. However, they *have* been used for gliding in *some* instances.

A more specific answer to *This* question, however, was undertaken by Scott Nisewander at *Nerdsync;* I  think you will find it very helpful and interesting.: