# When did Spider-Man lose his under-arm webbing?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, costume

In Spider-Man's first appearance, and most of the early comics that I have read, Spider-Man has some webbing underneath his arms [that were purely ornamental](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21172/13217):

[image: Amazing Fantasy #15]

However, at some point he seems to have lost the under-arm webbing, as seen in this comic from 1998:

[image: Amazing Spider-Man #434]

When did this happen exactly? And was there any particular reason, in-universe or out-of-universe, for the removal?

Comment: I'm not sure what's sadder, the fact that this is a [dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21172/what-are-the-webs-under-spideys-arms-for/21174#21174) or the fact that I know that it's a dupe.

Comment: @Richard That question asks about what the purpose of the under-arm webbing is. My question is when did the under-arm webbing stop being part of the costume.

Comment: "*When John Romita started drawing Spider-Man after Ditko left he drew the webbing smaller and smaller and eventually left them off, altogether."*. So [1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Romita_Sr.#Spider-Man) or thereabouts.

Comment: @Richard A tangental tidbit in an answer to a different question doesn't seem like it would make this question a duplicate. Besides, saying that it is in 1966 or so would be an excellent answer that goes beyond the scope of the other question's answer.

Comment: I've actually [run into this problem before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6387/13217), and it seems meta policy since then is that [answers don't make questions duplicates](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6953/13217). So I believe that this question should not be considered a duplicate of the other one about Spidey's underarm webbing because they are totally different questions, even if there is a bit of overlap in the answer.

Comment: 2 upvotes don't equate to a consensus of opinion, especially when that answer contradicts a far more highly voted answer with very extensive discussion behind it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It comes and goes. For some time prior to Amazing Spider-Man #231 (published August 1982), it was completely missing. While he is sewing a new suit during #231, Peter Parker comments on why it disappeared for some time:

> Of course, I'd have saved myself a lot of work, if I'd just silk-screened the design on the new bodysuits and let it go at that. But when I found a new supply of flex-nylon netting, I just couldn't resist putting the underarm webs back on my outfits. The netting on my old suit had ripped out long ago, and I couldn't find replacements for the longest time! I shouldn't have that problem now. This new brand is twice as tough as the old.
>
> Yeah, that's the ticket! From straight on you hardly know it's there. But spread the arms and-- TA-DAH!-- Ol' Web-pits is back!

In-universe, it disappeared due to wear-and-tear.

Comment: The armpit webbing also managed to make it into [one of the animated series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_(TV_series)), though I don't think it appeared again.

Answer (score 3):

Being someone who is currently reading The Amazing Spider-Man from start to finish, I can tell you that the webbing under Spider-Man's arms was originally Steve Ditko's vision... once John Romita took over, the webbing was still there from time to time but began to slowly get phased out. It was VERY soon after the 100th issue, when Stan Lee was replaced by Roy Thomas, was when Spider-Man's under arm webbing was permanently removed. Probably because the new artists kept forgetting to draw them in certain panels which lead to the decision to just remove them completely since they served no purpose to Spidey!

Comment: If you could pinpoint in which issue the webbing was permanently removed (and if there is an in-story reason for it, even better), I would consider marking this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Last occasion I saw the webbing was issue 99 page 13. After that, at the end of issue 100 Parker gets two extra pairs of arms that rip through the side of his suit. Although the arm-pit webbing isn't mentioned, I imagine Spidey just didn't repair the webbing once Dr Connors helped get rid of his extra arms

Comment: Could you [edit] in some evidence, such as images of the panels, to back this up?

Answer (score -1):

First thing that comes in mind:
"Hmm they removed Spidey's underarm wedding, looks like they don't want to spend some time drawing them."

Not saying it's laziness but I think it would be easier and faster to do Spidey drawings without the webbings.

There's this running gag the Philippines in the late 2000s that his webbings are his built-in deodorant.

Comment: This seems to answer part of the OPs question; do you have any information on *when* this change was made?